# Concept behind the Order of GL(2,Z3).

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

In the below image it is written (see underlined part) that after chosen the first row the second row has exactly $q^n -q$ possibilites. But i didn't get this. In my counter example it is not satisfied. Anyone one can help me to  understand this concept I am not able to get after 2nd , 3rd rows etc.[image: please see the image of page from book]

[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

You've counted one too much: the possibilities for the second row of an invertible matrix when the first one is $\begin{pmatrix}1&2\end{pmatrix}$ are exactly $$\begin{pmatrix}0&1\end{pmatrix}\\\begin{pmatrix}0&2\end{pmatrix}\\\begin{pmatrix}1&0\end{pmatrix}\\ \begin{pmatrix}1&1\end{pmatrix}\\ \begin{pmatrix}2&0\end{pmatrix}\\ \begin{pmatrix}2&2\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Where is (1 2) entry in first row in yoy list.

Comment: @GirishKumarChandora I don't know how many ways there are to read the English sentence "The possibilities for the second row of an invertible matrix when the first one is [...] are [list of rows]", but apparently the answer is "At least two".

Comment: can you explain this $q^n -q$ posibilities. I didnt get this one

Comment: I could, but in all honesty I would write what the author of the book wrote. Verbatim.

Comment: sorry.  In you answer u missed the one possibility of (1 2) which is  (2,1) . And therefore (1,2) has exactly 7 possibility. It will be helpful for me if u explain the counting techniques in GL(n,Zp)

Comment: @GirishKumarChandora I did not miss it: I purposedly avoided it. $(2,1)=2\cdot (1,2)$, therefore it must not be counted - and in fact $\det\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\ 2&1\end{pmatrix}=1-4=0$.

Comment: thnks for ur time for explaining.

Comment: how determinant :1-4=0

Comment: Because you are in $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$.